# Facebook XMPP server deletes custom tags?

Tags: facebook, xmpp

I'm trying to get an application to communicate via Facebook's XMPP server. For testing, I'm using the DIGEST-MD5 auth which works as advertised, and I'm able to send text messages from one user to another.

However, it seems every element that is not a `<body>` is removed from the message before getting routed by Facebook. So if my message contains both a `<body>` and a `<myOwnCustomTag>` element, then only `<body>` arrives; and if it only contains `<myOwnCustomTag>`, then no message is delivered at all.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebooks XMPP server is really only a frontend to their internal messaging system, so any custom data is probably lost in translation.

See the *Limitations* section here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/